# How does Facebook Music Object works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i'v built a music canvas application and i'm trying to figure out how the Facebook Music and Audio Objects work.

i did everything the [Open Graph Music Documentation Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/) said

here is my open graph meta tags for a song page.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="artist name - song name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song" />
<meta property="og:image" content="artist image url" />
<meta property="og:url" content="song page url" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="song mp3 url" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/vnd.facebook.bridge" />
<meta property="music:musician" content="artist page url" />
<meta property="music:album" content="song album url" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my app id" />
```

#### i'm not getting any erros but..

i debugged the url and this is what i'm getting

- no artist name.
- incorrect song title.
- no album name.
- when i publish the song url on my facebook status i'm not getting any audio player.

[image: image debug]
note: im getting the correct src i just deleted it from the image.

#### i'm trying to figure out how to deal with Open Graph beta Music Object for 2 days now.

can someone please help..

thanks in advance.

### edit:

if you look at the image i attached there is no artist name, album name and the title of the song is incorrect (facebook took that title from the mp3 filename) when i try adding `go:audio:title`, 'go:audio:artist`, 'go:audio:album` it works well but the facebook debugger returns error.

here is the debug information.
[image: debug info]

[image: music info]

Comment: Is your OG URL pointing to the URL with those tags on it, or to another URL with slightly different tags? (the linter will follow the og:url and scrape that)

Comment: yes its pointing, to the url with those tags on it.

Comment: Ah, then i'm not sure, it may well be a bug with the linter, because the general format of your tags seems fine to me

Answer (score 4):

Facebook states: "Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at this time." Are you whitelisted partner?

Answer (score 0):

og:audio:type should be application/mp3 to play, everything else seems fine to me

Comment: thanks i added a better explanation to the problem i'm having.

Comment: obviously it because of hebrew in url, try to url-encode it or try english urls, see if it works.

Comment: also I'm redirected to http://testappwebsite.dyndns-office.com/#/track/382/זהבה-בן-ודודו-אהרון-הלב-יודע-להאזנה/ which is different url, with different tags

Comment: i added the debugging information by image, it has nothing to do with the hebrew url. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. Just make sure that whatever you put in `og:url` is the actual page with the `<meta>` tags.

All `og:url` means is "Completely ignore this page and go over here to find the tags".

Comment: thanks for your answer i added better explanation to the problem I'm having.